# $("#grid").data("kendoGrid) undefined in $.getJSON success method in MVC Razor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have following Kendo.mvc grid

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BarCode)
                                <div style="padding-left:10%;padding-top:2%">
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.BarCodes)
                                .Name("grid")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(e => e.DocumentSetName)
                                    .Width(100)
                                    .Title("Reference No");
                                    columns.Bound(e => e.ScannedDate)
                                    .Title("Scanning Date")
                                    .Width(100);

                                })
                                .Sortable()
                                .Pageable()
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .PageSize(3)
                                    //.Read(read => read.Action("SearchUnregisteredIncomings", "Correspondence").Data("getSearchCriteria"))
                                )
                                .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                                    )
```

and this is the ajax call I have made

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Search")', {ReferenceNumber:'123'
    }, function (data, status) {
         var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.data(data);
        grid.refresh();

        $("#loading").stop().fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

The grid variable is undefined.
The following is the names and sequence of .js files and scripts that are loaded in _Layout.cshtml file.

```
 <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/spin.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the below scripts loaded after @RenderBody() section but before `</body>` tag

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/spcontext.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js">/script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/wysiwyg/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/wysiwyg/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/assets/treeview.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/assets/form-validation.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
            $(".uniform_on").uniform();
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            $('.textarea').wysihtml5();
        });
        (function (window, undefined) {      
            var $ = window.jQuery;
            var document = window.document;    

            $(document).ready(function () {                    
               //some code here
            });
        })(window);
```

I think the problem is due to the sequence of .js files but can not figure it out.

Comment: You have three different versions of jQuery included..

Comment: Have tried after removing all the jQuery file except for 1.10.2,but still no success.

Comment: I'm also not exactly sure I follow what you are trying to do.  You have a data binding defined in your grid already - so are you trying to rebind it?

Comment: Yes I make ajax call when search button in my html is clicked and binding the search result to the grid

Comment: Make sure jQuery and Kendo are loaded in the `<head>`